# Exit a switch/case function before the break;

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, switch-statement

I need to leave the function switch/case when I reach the line that proves that any term vector answer1 is unlike any term vector rightAnswer1 (within the conditional: "answer1[i1] != rightAnswer1[i1]")

```
switch (currentFrame)
{
    case 1:
        for (var i1:int = 0; i1 < 8; i1++)
        {
            if (answer1[i1] != rightAnswer1[i1])
            {                   
                anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 2;
                trace("Answer " + i1 + " is wrong!");
                break; // I need to leave the switch/case function here
            }
        }

        trace("Answer is right!");
        anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 1;

        break;

    case 2:
        for (var i2:int = 0; i2 < 3; i2++)
        {
            if (answer2[i2] != rightAnswer2[i2])
            {                   
                anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 2;
                break;
            }
        }           
        anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 1;
        break;

    default:
        trace("ERROR");
    break;
}

if (anyArray[currentFrame - 1] == 1)
    light.play();
else
    error.play();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass a label to the break statement indicating the scope want to break out to:

```
outside:
switch (currentFrame)
{
    case 1:
        for (var i1:int = 0; i1 < 8; i1++)
        {
            if (answer1[i1] != rightAnswer1[i1])
            {                   
                anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 2;
                trace("Answer " + i1 + " is wrong!");
                break outside; 
            }
        }

        trace("Answer is right!");
        anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 1;

        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

While you could add a label as *cleong* answered, I would suggest steering clear of them as they tend to needlessly complexify the code. Every time you think you need to add labels, there is probably a cleaner and clearer way to handle the situation.

For example: in this particular piece of code, you could write a function that handles the validation, thus removing the need for labels AND removing all the redundancy in your cases.

```
switch (currentFrame)
{
    case 1:
        validateAnswer(answer1, rightAnswer1);
        break;

    case 2:
        validateAnswer(answer2, rightAnswer2);
        break;

    default:
        trace("ERROR");
        break;
}
```

...snip...

```
private function validateAnswer(userAnswer:Array, rightAnswer:Array):Boolean
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < rightAnswer.length; i++)
    {
        if (userAnswer[i] != rightAnswer[i])
        {                   
            anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 2; //assuming that anyArray and currentFrame are class members
            return false;
        }
    }           
    anyArray[currentFrame - 1] = 1;
    return true;
}
```

I believe that your code would be much more readable, scalable and less error prone that way.